# Oracle RAC Maintenance

Tags: performance, oracle-12c, database-recommendation, oracle-rac

Is it possible to keep one node running in 2 node cluster while keeping  one node down for Maintenance?.I want to do this as we are planning some hardware upgrades.

Comment: Yes. That is the point of high availability.

Answer (score 1):

It is actual quite easy if you are obvious of some caveats:

- configure your services to run on one node only: `srvctl modify service -db $DATABASE -service $SERVICENAME -preferred $INSTANCE1 -available $INSTANCE2 -modifyconfig`
- wait for the sessions to wander to the node running $INSTANCE1. This may take some time, it's heavily dependent on the type of application you are running. JAVA Applications tend to reconnect quite frequently. So check with your database, e.g. query `gv$session`.
- Take down your node and do whatever maintenance there is to do
- Reconfigure your services to run on the second node:

  1. `srvctl modify service -db $DATABASE -service $SERVICENAME -preferred "$INSTANCE1,$INSTANCE2" -modifyconfig`
  2. `srvctl start service -db $DATABASE -service $SERVICENAME -node $NODE` *This step is crucial, if you omit it, the whole procedure won't work!*
  3. `srvctl modify service -db $DATABASE -service $SERVICENAME -preferred $INSTANCE2 -available $INSTANCE1 -modifyconfig`
- wait again for the sessions to wander to your patched node
- Take down your second node and do whatever maintenance there is to do
- reconfigure your services to run on both nodes and start the services

  1. `srvctl modify service -db $DATABASE -service $SERVICENAME -preferred "$INSTANCE1,$INSTANCE2" -modifyconfig`
  2. `srvctl start service -db $DATABASE -service $SERVICENAME`

The procedure must be tested in your environment as there may be dependencies e.g. if you use a shared ORACLE_HOME on ACFS. The success of reconfiguration of services *must* be tested, especially if you have client-server applications.